# Accessing CSV file generated by Java program from a database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, csv

I have a database in XAMPP and I am using Eclipse IDE. I have to take the database contents and put them into a csv file. My code is not showing errors as such. It is executing perfectly.

I am not getting the output CSV file, in spite of the code working perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userregistration";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";

        String csvFilePath = "Users-export.csv";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)){
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM usertable";
            Statement stt = con.createStatement();

            //Select DB
            ResultSet res = stt.executeQuery(sql);

            BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFilePath));

            // write header line containing column names       
            fileWriter.write("name,password");

            while(res.next())
            {
                String Name = res.getString("name");
                String Password = res.getString("password");

                String line = String.format("\"%s\",%s",
                        Name, Password);

                fileWriter.newLine();
                fileWriter.write(line); 
            }
            System.out.println("Successful");
            stt.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Datababse error:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File IO error:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MySQL can save table to CSV itself ([SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)) - java work is to execute this query only.

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger yet?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Akina, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @nitind, yeah. My code has no errors as such and it is printing "Successful". I just have issues accessing the CSV file itself.

Comment: @halfer. I am asking a question here for the first time and I genuinely have deadline. I did not know the rules but I was not trying to be rude. Sorry if it came off that way. I apologize. I am still learning and thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: What do you mean by issues accessing the csv file itself? What are the issues?

Comment: @nitind, I am unable to find the file on my system. I have tried using Notepad, but to no avail. So, either it has not been created or I am going wrong somewhere in the way I am trying to access it. Either way, I need help. Also, if there is a possibility that it has not been created, I wonder why it would display the "Successful" message.

Comment: @halfer, I wish I had the answer for your question, but I don't. I am sorry. Thank you for pointing it out to me. I sincerely hope you get your answers. Thank you.

Comment: It should default to what ever the working directory is when you run your application. Check your application launcher in the Run -> Run Configurations... dialog. If that fails, create a java.io.File with your csv's file path and ask it for its canonical and absolute paths.

Comment: @nitind, you solved this question which I have been stuck with for so much time now. Thank you so much for being my saviour. I am asking a question here for the first time and don't know how to accept your answer though. I can't see any green checkpoint beside your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that the output file's location was unknown--it should default to what ever the working directory is when you run your application. Check your application launcher in the Run -> Run Configurations... dialog. If that fails, create a java.io.File with your csv's file path and ask it for its canonical and absolute paths.